# setStringValue with void method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a button (`IBAction`), when I click the button a label will change (`setStringValue`).
Works perfectly.

Is there a way for changing a label (`setStringValue`) with a (`void`) method, so a method that is not an `IBAction`. Because if I call the method nothing happens? The code is illustrated below.

```
//IBAction method, label is changed to setLabelMethod, works perfect.

-(IBAction)setLabel:(id)sender{
  [labelA setStringValue:@"Works!"];
  ClassName *MyClass = [[ClassName alloc]init];
  [MyClass methodSetLabel]
}

//void method, nothing happens
-(void)methodSetLabel{
  [labelB setStringValue:@"Works!"];
}
```

What do I have to do to make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IBAction` methods are `void`. The reason nothing happens is different from what you think: it's not because the method is `void`, it's because the *instance* on which you call the method is wrong.

Your `setLabel` method creates a new instance of `MyClass`. That's not the class that has the real `labelB` displayed on your screen.

You need to call the method on the same object that owns the label and runs the `setLabel:` method. In Objective C this object is represented by a special variable called `self`. If you rewrite the method as follows

```
-(IBAction)setLabel:(id)sender{
    [labelA setStringValue:@"Works!"];
    [self methodSetLabel];
}
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it Works!
But... how can I call the same methodSetLabel from another Class. I have a myView class. Within this class (myView) I have a keyboard event method. So if a key is pressed the method methodSetLabel has to be called and the label has to change.
I tried this:

    [self methodSetLabel];

But I get an error: "No visible @interface for 'MyView' declares the selector setStringValue.

Comment: @Pidaji To change a label from another class, the object of that other class must get an access to the object that holds the label that needs to change. The instance can be passed in at initialization, or obtained through some well-known location (e.g. a singleton).

Comment: Thanks again! Forgive me for my lack of knowledge. I'm quite new to objective-c/cocoa. 
Can you tell me how I could pass in the instance with initialization?

Comment: @Pidaji I'd rather avoid prolonged discussions in the comments. That would be a different question, which you should ask separately. This would let you get an answer or two from people who can explain things much better than me.

Comment: @Pidaji If you understand the answer to your original question, consider accepting an answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: I marked your answer. I will search some more on the net and if I cant find the right answer for my problem I will ask a new question. Thanks again for your help.